# Can we connect to Oracle database from Unix system without OCCI?

Tags: c++, unix, oracle11g, occi, instantclient

Can we connect to Oracle database from Unix system without OCCI? Is it necessary for a Instant Client to be installed to use the Database connection?

Kindly give suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one you're asking here, but the real problem you think gets solved by not installing Open Client.

Comment: I am trying to work out the code in the following link. I am facing problem that occi.h file to be included which is available from the rpm packages given from the link. so my doubt is without using occi can we able to connect Oracle. If yes can you share some samples.                                                                                                   http://oradim.blogspot.in/2009/08/getting-started-with-occi-linux-version_16.html